# area map onclick sumbit not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, submit

Hi I have the code below its not working ( I cant click on the area map and its not submitting the form):

```
<form method="post" action="" style="margin:0; padding:0">
<input type="hidden" name="myForm" id="myForm" value="ADPR">
<input type="hidden" name="Product_Code" value="50347">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Screen" value="OINF">
<input type="hidden" name="Attributes" value="Yes">
<input type="hidden" name="Store_Code" value="AP">

<img src="test.jpg" alt="" width="622" height="86" usemap="#Map" border="0">
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="514,68,622,86" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById("myForm").submit()" alt="Submit request" nohref >
  </map>
  </form>
```

the error i get : Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'submit'

can you help me?

Comment: Please don't edit your OP with the "fixed" version of your code.  Doing this renders all the answers totally meaningless, exposes them to undeserved down-votes, and discourages new answers.  If an answer solves your problem, please just click the check-mark to "accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have not defined an id for your form. `myForm` is the id of your input not your form.
- Use single quotes to escape your `onclick` event handler: `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the id of your form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="" style="margin:0; padding:0">
```

Comment: do you know why this is not working though : style="cursor:pointer;" its not showing a cursor where the area map is?